# Find the latest log file from multiple servers

Tags: python-3.x

For our daily monitoring we need to access 16 servers of a particular application and find the latest log file on one of those servers (it usually generates on the first 8).

The problem is that this code is giving me the latest file from each server instead of providing the latest log file from the entire group of servers.

Also, since this is an hourly activity, once the file is processed, it gets archived, so many of the servers don't have any log files present in them at a particular time. Due to this, while the below code is getting executed, I get - `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` response and the code stops at server 3 if server 4 does not have any log files.

I tried adding `default = 0` argument to `latest_file` but it gives me the error message `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int`

Can you please help me out here? I am using Python 3.8 and PyCharm.

This is what I have so far :

```
import glob
import os
import re

paths = [r'\\Server1\Logs\*.log',
         r'\\Server2\Logs\*.log',
         .....
         r'\\Server16\Logs\*.log']


for path in paths:
    list_of_files = glob.glob(path)
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    f = open(os.path.join(latest_file), "r")
    print(latest_file)
```

Comment: Why not build a list of log files across all servers, inside the loop, *then* find the max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list first and then find the max.

```py
import glob
import os
import re

paths = [r'\\Server1\Logs\*.log',
         r'\\Server2\Logs\*.log',
         .....
         r'\\Server16\Logs\*.log']

list_of_files = []
for path in paths:
    list_of_files.extend(glob.glob(path))

if list_of_files:
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    f = open(os.path.join(latest_file), "r")
    print(latest_file)
else:
    print("No log files found!")
```

Comment: @abhulb can you please help me with opening the latest file captured in normal string form?

' f = open(os.path.join(latest_file), "r")
print(.f.read())'

opens the file with each character spaced out like-

**T h i s**


Because of this, i am unable to use my multiple regex patterns to find a few strings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. Could you post it as a separate question with proper explanation

Comment: @abhulb just updated the comment. Sorry I pressed enter key in error earlier so the question was half complete.

Comment: Not sure what the reason could be. Nothing seems to be wrong with your code. Try opening the file with some editor and check if the data is proper in that file.