# Python - Regex pattern from a log file

Tags: python

I previously raised [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836604/find-the-latest-log-file-from-multiple-servers/59836821?noredirect=1#comment105840979_59836821) where I wanted to find the latest file from a set of servers. This was answered thanks to this community.

Now another problem I am facing is that when I try to find a regex pattern match within the latest log file, I am getting a blank result i.e. the program cannot find the match even though notepad++ matches my pattern with the string I want [I just wanted to check if my pattern was at fault].

I want to search for 3 different patterns within the same file and I have tried the below code but still no output:

```
import glob
import os
import re

paths = [r'\\Server1\Logs\*.log',
         r'\\Server2\Logs\*.log',
         .....
         r'\\Server16\Logs\*.log']

list_of_files = []
for path in paths:
    list_of_files.extend(glob.glob(path))
#Find the latest log file from all the servers:
if list_of_files:
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    f = open(os.path.join(latest_file), "r")
    s = f.read()

#Search for the required pattern:
    pattern1 = re.search(r"[A-Z\s]{4}\_[A-Z\s]{8}\_[A-Z\s]{4}\_[0-9.]{4}[A-Z\s]{3}\"\]\s\-\s[a-z\s]{8}", s)
    pattern2 = re.search(r"[A-Z]{4}\_[A-Z]{5}\_[A-Z]{4}\_[0-9]{1}\_[0-9]{8}\_[0-9.]{7}[A-Z]{3}\"\]\s\-\s[a-z]{8}", s)
    pattern3 = re.search(r"[A-Z]{4}\_[A-Z]{4}\_[0-9]{1}\_[0-9]{8}\_[0-9.]{7}[A-Z]{3}\"\]\s\-\s[a-z]{8}", s)
    print(pattern1)
    print(pattern2)
    print(pattern3)
    print(latest_file)
else:
    print("No log files found!")
```

**Please note that I have tried re.findall an other re methods as well but to no success.**
**I have also tried to use `for line in s` and then pattern search in line but again, no success.**

Apologies if this has a simple solution that I am not able to grasp but since I am new to the concept of programming itself, any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

As advised by the community, below is the sample of the log file that I am trying to find my pattern in:

```
Full line of random data that is not important to me
Another full line of random data that is not important to me
.
.
.
.
.
Yet another full line of random data that is not important to me
Upload of ["\\DATA01-ABC\companyname.projectname.appname\Production\WORD-Outbound\ProcessNameAndFile\WORD_ACTIVITY_FILE_010.DAT"] - complete.
```

**WORD_ACTIVITY_FILE_010.DAT"] - complete** this is what I want to match.

As this log is something that I don't think I can paste on the internet, I have replaced the desired output with random words that hopefully make sense.

Comment: Can you post sample logs required for matching pattern?

Comment: @Gagan T K I have now edited the question to include sample logs required for matching pattern1.

Comment: Thanks for the sample logs. I'm able to match `pattern1` with the sample logs you've provided and I'm able to print it too. What exactly it is printing with your print statement?

Comment: @GaganTK I dont get any output when I try and run it.

Can you please tell me if you've tried it by saving the "logs" in a .log file and then read it to find the patter? [I am not sure if this matters but just wanted to ask for my sake.]

Also, is it possible for you to provide the code that provides an output? [if its different from what I posted ]

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Dz66HyXE Here's what I have tried. I have saved your sample logs as 'ser.log' file and used in the code

Comment: This is the error message I am getting when I try your code- [just replaced 'ser.log' to a log file location i downloaded on my local system to test]

- 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Are you able to read the file (`print(s)`)? and does the file contain word similar to `WORD_ACTIVITY_FILE_010.DAT"] - complete`?

Comment: Yes... when I print(s), I can see `WORD_ACTIVITY_FILE_010.DAT"] - complete` present in it.

Comment: If you're using the same code that I've tried then it should work right? I'm not able figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after adding "utf-16" argument to 'f' variable which was reading our **.log** file.
Before the code was reading the log file in ASCII mode which resulted in each character in the log file spaced out.

This fixed the issue for me:

```
f = codecs.open(os.path.join(latest_file), "r", "utf-16")
```